# The Sprites and ColorLayers in cocos2d-python doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, cocos2d-python

I've tested pyglet and I'm sure pyglet works well.
But when I ran the script in `samples/hello_world_actions.py` , or anything with color, only thing in the Scene is Label.
Could anyone tell me what has happend?

PS:my env :
Python2.7 cocos2d 0.5.0 pyglet 1.1.4
Windows7

Answer (score 1):

I try to rollback the graphics driver to the old version, the issue is resolved.